# "Cannot redeclare class" error on Heroku but not on another host

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

After making a few changes to a Laravel app on Heroku, it's giving me errors about having redeclared a class. I'm not having any issues with the app locally but when I go to any of the pages on the Heroku instance, it returns a blank page. Checking the Heroku logs I found:

```
2015-03-02T19:39:55.262777+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=evening-thicket-7595.herokuapp.com request_id=dfeaab25-aea0-4b74-8d03-bf6b951738bd fwd="107.19.188.77" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=172ms status=500 bytes=208
2015-03-02T19:39:55.257645+00:00 app[web.1]: [02-Mar-2015 19:39:55 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests in /app/storage/framework/compiled.php on line 4541
2015-03-02T19:39:55.259229+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.93.58.218 - - [02/Mar/2015:19:39:55 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36
2015-03-02T19:39:55.958088+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=evening-thicket-7595.herokuapp.com request_id=63dbc93e-88b0-47f6-a8f4-ecc385ed9a9a fwd="107.19.188.77" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=245
2015-03-02T19:39:55.954089+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.93.58.218 - - [02/Mar/2015:19:39:55 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36
```

I've searched the pages I've recently edited and I'm not seeing where this class is being called again. The only place I see the declaration is on the original Controller class. Again, it's working fine locally in Homestead.

Is there something specific to Heroku that would cause this error?

Comment: It's trying to redeclare the class inside `compiled.php`.  Maybe try regenerating that with the command `php artisan clear-compiled`

Comment: It's best to introduce your problem directly and finish with a specific question, rather than asking for ideas.